# How to use export plug in Grails?

Tags: grails

I'm pretty new to Grails so need some suggestions in implementing the export to Excel using export plugin.

I have installed the export plug in and used the following code in gsp to display the download option.

First time the page gets loaded the params are being set and the data is fetched from DB using those params, the data is then converted to JSON and listed in jqGrid.

When the download is clicked the controller is called again and params are different this time
so how can I get the previous params values so that I can call DB again for fetching the data and exporting to excel.

Is there any way that I can pass previous param values while calling download method.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean. I recently implemented a similar feature, that when a user clicks the "Export to Excel" button it generates the file and returns it to the user to save or open.

Comment: This is what i need so can you please share how did u implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Export tag have the attribute named params. It accepts Map value. You can add the paramerter there.
Eg.,  params = "[startDate : startDate]" or 
      params = "${params}"

In your downloadIncidentListExcel action, again you need to construct your list to get download.